# Poor throughput to the internet but just fine locally.

Tags: router, switch, throughput

I have a router (Linksys E4200) connected to the internet (via external modem) and connected to a Powerline (AV500) device. I have 2 computers connected as follows:

```
Modem <-- 1GbE --> Router <- 100MbE -> Powerline <---> Computer1
Modem <-- 1GbE --> Router <-- 1GbE --> Computer2
```

1. Throughput between Computer1 and Computer2 using HTTP/SMB is good (near 100mb).
2. Throughput between Computer2 and the internet is good (>150mb down).
3. Throughput between Computer1 and the internet is bad* (<20mb down).

   - When downloading with a single TCP connection.

I don't understand how #3 can happen when #1 and #2 are fine.

---

To make things even more confusing, when I update the network as shown below by adding a switch between the router and the powerline it seems to fix the problem entirely.

```
Modem <-- 1GbE --> Router <-- 1GbE --> Switch <- 100MbE -> Powerline <---> Computer1
```

What can be causing the issue? Is there any way I can resolve this without keeping the switch there? I've also tried a second switch (cheaper brand) and that one didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the operating system on computer 1 and the delay introduced by the powerline adapters, you may need to explicitely raise the tcp window size on computer 1

How to do this depends on the operating system

Also because you go through from 1GBit to 100Mbit and your internet connection is faster than 100Mbit, you will experience burst of lost packets there (happened to me a couple of weeks ago, spend some good hours to figure it out). Combined with higher latencies opposed to local transfer, this leads to significant speed fluctuations, worse than you would expect.

If the switch is managed and keeps port counters you can check for dropped packets on the ethernet port that goes to the powerline adapter.

Comment: This is certainly possible.  The way for the OP to check this is to start an `mtr` on some internet host for 20 minutes before starting a large transfer (perhaps download an ISO DVD image).  Now the OP has a baseline for his packet loss.  Keep the original `mtr` running, and now start an ISO download.  If drop rates change *inside your home network*, you have identified this answer as a strong possibility

Comment: In my case it was really weird, no loss, no big surge in response time. But speed going up and down wildly, without the link being saturated by other traffic (but there was other traffic, 10-30% of the link capacity). Took me some time until I had a look on switch counters and saw short bursts of dropped output packets (dozens at a time). Replacing with 1GB link and everything was fine. Still not sure why tcp was not able to cope and find a "sweetspot" speed.

Comment: So those "short bursts of dropped output packets" would (eventually) be detected by `mtr`.  The switch doesn't care whether the packet is TCP or ICMP... it just has overloaded buffers and drops indiscriminately

Comment: They were in short burst, not spread evenly in time, mtr would maybe pickup one or two, not enough to get my attention